# Deploying nodejs app on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy nodejs application on heroku using the tutorial in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

I could deploy it successfully but while running the app using 'heroku open' command, new window opens in my default browser but throws and Application error

And in the logs, I see an error message as shown below

**2016-07-29T11:12:17.083232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=9c18023a-f759-4481-9308-2a80ea05958f fwd="180.151.40.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=**

*my-app - all the apps that I have created so far.

Could anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to look around that error to see how the app crashed. There will be a stack trace above the H10.

Comment: hunterlofits, all I could see only the above mentioned message from the application logs screen in heroku website "https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/my-app/logs"
Is there anyway to find the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

The error H10 occurs when a web dyno crashes : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Most likely you are not specifying a port that heroku can dynamically set for your application. You can add the following to you server code when you listen on a specific port:

```
..., .listen(process.env.PORT || your_port)
```

Try this and your application might run without crashing. Good Luck.

Comment: Here I am trying to access an application that deployed in heroku server. If I hit url https://my-app.herokuapp.com/ in the browser and app should work.
Do I have to still specify the port for this? 
Can you brief me on this?

Comment: @AshwinKumar In your node application, you have to specify a port on which the application 's server will listen to requests, however you don't need to specify the port with the application link, heroku takes care of that. Have you included `process.env.PORT` in your node application and deployed?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have missed out adding a listener to the app.